# Given IV as type String not 16 bytes long - AES decryption in python

Tags: python, aes

So I am fairly new to AES en/decryption and I want to decrypt a message, which was encrypted via AES256 (Rjindael).
I was given a key and a IV, both as string. Cyphermode is cbc, If this matters.

I use the Crypto Library.

```
key = "some_key"
iv = "some_iv"
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
message = Crypto.Util.Padding.unpad(cipher.decrypt(ct), AES.block_size)
```

This code gives me and Error saying 'IV must be 16 bytes long'.
I added this under iv but this did not change anything

```
iv = bytes(iv,'utf-8')
```

What am I missing here? I am sure it is some basic concept which I missed, so I'd be glad, if you could help out

Comment: Well, how long *is* the IV?  (I assume it's not literally "some_iv".)

Comment: Maybe the IV is encoded, e.g. with Base64. Then it must be decoded first.  The same can apply to key and ciphertext.

Comment: the iv String is 24 characters long. Thought that one char is one byte, so it does not fit as the Error suggested. Tho, I am pretty convinced that the IV is correct itself. I thought I did not understand that i would need to transfer it into something not human-readable

Comment: 24 bytes indicates a Base64 encoding. Base64 decoded this corresponds to 16 bytes. A base64 decoding is possible e.g. with `base64.b64decode(...)`.

Comment: really helpful, thank you ! If its not too much to explain, I'd be interested how you know that a 24byte string has something to do with base64 decoding

Comment: [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is a commonly used binary-to-text encoding. And it has an overhead of about 33%, which is 8 bytes for 24 bytes, so the data is 16 bytes, as it must be with an IV for AES.